# Questions with [angular*] and [x-editable] should be tagged with [angular*] and [angular-xeditable]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Questions tagged with [angular*] and [x-editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x-editable) should be tagged instead with [angular*] and [angular-xeditable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-xeditable) because x-editable and Angular-xeditable are two different libraries.